# Calling a value from a constructor

Tags: c#

Can someone help me how to get the value of the string `x` and put it to another class? I want to use the value of string `x` in another class.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Titles : Form
    {
        public Titles(string strToDisplay)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string x = strToDisplay;
        }

        private void titleList_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // USE X HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a global variable: `private string X;` and in the constructor put: `X = strToDisplay`

Comment: I think you only have 1 class and 2 methods. So make it an instance field or property.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access method scoped variable outside that method. You need to declare that variable at class level and reuse it.

```
private string x;
public Titles(string strToDisplay)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        x = strToDisplay;
    }


    private void titleList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Now you can access here
    }
```

Comment: can you help me again? Im trying to `SELECT recipeName from recipetitles where ingredientName LIKE ' %{ listBox1.Items }% ' ` and it will read  `while (dr.Read()){titleList.Items.Add(dr["recipeName"].ToString());}` My problem is that the things that it read doesnt add in to my listbox

Comment: in my listbox1 I have a set of items like egg, scallop, chicken, oil, eggplant and i want to select all the recipe names that have a egg, scallop, chicken, oil, eggplant in their ingredient. what part am i missing?

Comment: Without knowing structure of your table, I can't give my suggestion precisely. However, based on your comment, you query return 0 items so your reader is empty. You need to make dynamic query for this : first make like clause with each item of listbox like `string whereLikeClause = "WHERE 1 = 1 "; for(int i=0;i<listBox1.Items.Count;i++{ whereLikeClause += $" AND ingredientName LIKE %{listBox1.Items[i].ToString()} "}; string query = $"SELECT recipeName from recipetitles {whereLikeClause }"`

Comment: btw what is the purpose of this syntax `string whereLikeClause = "WHERE 1 = 1 ";` ?

Comment: m having error that says check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '%Egg Scallop... at line 1. btw i have a table `CREATE TABLE recipeTitles( recipeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, recipeName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, ingredientName VARCHAR(900) NOT NULL, category VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );` i tried adding \n in my command `new MySqlCommand($"SELECT recipeName" + "\n"+ "from recipetitles { whereLikeClause }", con);` but still it got the same error

Comment: it's just for writing where query easily. You need to inspect your generated query and see what's wrong with that.

Comment: thanks i find the error and my program is working fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the parameter in a class field:

```
class Titles
{
    private string strToDisplayField;
    public Titles(string strToDisplay)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        strToDisplayField = strToDisplay;
    }


    private void titleList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var local = strToDisplayField; // Is accessible here
    }
}
```

Comment: why is that when i try to put the variable local in to a message box it would not be seen?

Comment: @aaa It should work, put a break point and inspect the values at runtime.

Comment: @aaa Maybe this tutorial will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A&feature=youtu.be&t=2m34s

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access within the class, make `x` a field.

```
public class Titles
{
    private string x;
    public Titles(string strToDisplay)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.x = strToDisplay;
    }

    private void titleList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newX = this.x;
    }
}
```

If you want to access outside of the class, make `x` a public property.

```
public class Titles
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public Titles(string strToDisplay)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.X = strToDisplay;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    private void titleList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t = new Titles("Some text");
        var newX = t.X;

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your first suggestion but when i try to put the variable x in to a message box it would not pop/show?

Comment: @aaa You need to share more of your code. What you are trying to do and how you are trying to do that? And read about *variable scope* in C#/.Net http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx